# Epiphany browser error

Tags: raspbian, web-browsers

I am trying to run epiphany browser in fullscreen mode. I tried using this command in terminal ;

```
epiphany-browser -a --profile http://www.google.com

--profile must be an existing directory when --application-mode is requested
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Almost all command line interfaces have [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).  Here's an excerpt from a copy of `man epiphany-browser` I found online:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> epiphany [OPTION...] [url]
>
> --profile=FILE
>
> Profile directory to use in the private instance

`-a` isn't in [the copy I found](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/epiphany-browser/), but it should be in yours (type `man epiphany-browser` at the command prompt); I'm guessing it's the short form of `--application-mode`.  If that requires an argument, you should provide it.

If not, you should be fine by either getting rid of `--profile`, or providing an arg for that as well.  You could also try `--` (notice the spaces) before the URL; some CLI's respect this to indicate the end of arguments:

```
epiphany-browser -a --profile -- http://www.google.com
```

Of course, this is still an error since the `--profile` is pointless with no arg, but it may not be fatal and the URL may be recognized as such.